# don't know the equation of the function but want to plot it

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I know how to plot a function if i know the equation but in this case i don't know the equation of itself , thus i want to plot it by using some curve or approximation command

[image]

thanks for the help

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: (-1) for no effort and this site does not help in finding equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you do not want to guess these functions but nevertheless...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/symmetric axes/.style={code={
\draw[thick,-stealth] (0,-#1) -- (0,#1);
\draw[thick,-stealth] (-#1,0) -- (#1,0);}},pics/symmetric axes/.default=5]

 \pic{symmetric axes};
 \draw[red,thick] plot[variable=\x,domain=-4:4,smooth] ({\x},{2*tanh(\x)+0.5*\x});

 \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
  \pic{symmetric axes};
  \draw[red,thick] plot[variable=\x,domain=-4:4,smooth] ({pow(\x,3)/8-\x},{\x});
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: actually i really want to the know the functions sometimes but don't know how to find em , thanks for the help

Comment: @Quintis [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462730/121799) you can find a collection of options.

Comment: how do you know the equation of these functions so precisely ?

Comment: @Quintis Living in a burrow helps. ;-) Most of the standard plots can be reproduced by some combination of polynomials, exp, tanh, and the trigonometric functions.