# Twisted Pair Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to draw a twisted pair using Tikz. Its shape reminds me to draw a series of sin functions, but i don't sincerly know how to do that (how to draw the cables). The result I'd like to obtain is like this  (sorry for the quality, I couldn't do it better)

[image]

Thanks in advance to everybody!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `knots` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fat line/.style={black, double=#1,double
    distance=6pt,looseness=1.2,line cap=round}]
\begin{knot}[%draft mode = crossings, % uncomment to see where the crossings are
    clip width = 0,
    flip crossing = 2]
\strand[fat line=gray]
    (0,0) to[out=20,in=180] (2,-1) to[out=0,in=160] (4,0); 
\strand[fat line=white]
    (0,-1) to[out=-20,in=180] (2,0) to[out=0,in=200] (4,-1); 
\end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how can i add more lines? I tried editing \strand by adding "to [out=x, in=y] (6,-1)" but I don't know how to set x and y. How can i calculate them?

Comment: @frad The arguments of `out` and `in` are just angles. So `out=20` means that the curve goes out under an angle of 20 degrees.

Comment: yup, I already knew this, but I don't know what values I should write to get a perfect shape. I mean: I edited your code into this "\strand (0,0) to[out=20,in=180] (1,-0.5) to[out=0,in=160] (2,0) to[out=-20,in=140] (3,-0.5);" but the wire is not clean. I'd like to draw several paths like the main one

Comment: @frad I can only answer this if I now how the result should look like. Some basic methods of drawing smooth curves are collected e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462730/194703). You may want to use the `hobby` library by LoopSpace, the same author as `knots`. Maybe [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/532797/194703) helps you to achieve what you want.

Comment: I mean something like this https://ya-webdesign.com/imgdownload.html

Comment: @frad Your link does not show an image (for me), probably your browser has a setting that remembers a choice which my browser does not know. Also I feel that this is a separate question. You could plot a function and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105618/discussion-between-frad-and-schrodingers-cat).

Comment: @frad I will be busy for a while but what prevents you from asking a separate question on this? (I believe to have answered the original one.)